# Make wp_tag_cloud look like cloud (the words should overlap)

Tags: php, wordpress

Can I get wp_tag_cloud (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud) to look like either of these two pictures?

This is how it looks like today: site

This is the php I'm useing:

```
<?php 
  $args = array(
    'taxonomy'  => 'category', 
   ); 

  wp_tag_cloud($args);
?>
```

But when I add 'orderby' => 'name' for example, the page goes blank.

[image: Picture one]

[Picture two http://paul.kedrosky.com/WindowsLiveWriter/ATagCloudintheLifeofCNBC_E14B/cnbc-cloud_thumb.png](http://paul.kedrosky.com/WindowsLiveWriter/ATagCloudintheLifeofCNBC_E14B/cnbc-cloud_thumb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution became something like this:

.tag-link-10 {font-size:13px !important;text-transform:lowercase;}/* Annons */
.tag-link-5 {font-size:16px !important;text-transform:uppercase;font-style:italic;}/* Film */

I had to style each tag separately. Though i didn't get them to overlap.

Answer (score 1):

the tag cloud **WILL** look like this , but it depends on your theme , or more precicely , the CSS that is assigned to the #tag_cloud ID.

If your tag cloud looks different now, you should edit your css to suit your needs , for example :

```
#tag_cloud a:link {
    font-family: georgia;
    color: red;
}

#tag_cloud a:hover {
    font-family: georgia;
    color: green;
}

#tag_cloud a:visited {
    font-family: georgia;
    color: blue;
}
```

also , wp_tag_cloud() function can recieve parameters , like

```
    smallest'                  => 8, 
    'largest'                   => 22,
    'unit'                      => 'pt', 
    'number'                    => 45,
```

where smallest is the size of the smallest tag (less frequent) the larget is the largest size, the unit is the units used for that numeric value of size , and the number is the number of tags in the cloud .
Probably your theme has modified either the css or the function parameters .

You can read more here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud

If you are not familiar with CSS or PHP, I suggest you would read some more , or post the direct link to your problem and aske for someone to help you fix it .

Comment: Look in my question, I've added a link to the page. Would be great if you could look at it!

Comment: what is wrong with your tag cloud ? it looks like the first example you gave (b&w) - only that you would need a bit more tags to make it more dense ..

Comment: The thing is that I want them to overlap as shown in the two pictures. Thougth it would be possible..